# How to use "in" operator for alphabets while looping in python?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, operator-keyword

I am trying the Following question:

A website requires the users to input username and password to register.

Write a program to check the validity of password input by users.

- Following are the criteria for checking the password:

  1. At least 1 letter between [a-z]
  2. At least 1 number between [0-9]
  3. At least 1 letter between [A-Z]
  4. At least 1 character from [$#@]
  5. Minimum length of transaction password: 6
  6. Maximum length of transaction password: 12

Your program should accept a sequence of comma separated passwords and will check them according to the above criteria. Passwords that match the criteria are to be printed, each separated by a comma.

- Example If the following passwords are given as input to the program:
  ABd1234@1,a F1#,2w3E*,2We3345 Then, the output of the program should
  be: ABd1234@1

**However for my python code:**

```
values=input("Enter the set of passwords :")
list1=[]
list1=values.split(',')
num1=0
num2=0
num3=0
num4=0
for i in list1:
    num1=len(i)
    if(num1>=6 and num1<=12):
        for z in i:
            if (z.isupper()):
                num1=1
            if(z.islower()):
                num2=1
            if(z.isdigit()):
                num3=1
            if(z in ('#','$','@')) :
                print(z)
                num4=1
    if(num1+num2+num3+num4==4):
        print(i)
    else:
        print("passkey failed")
```

Why I am getting the last passkey as correct despite not passing criteria.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: yes I did tried to debug, I am learning this language as a newbie. I now found my mistake, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your counters never get de-incremented. After the first correct passkey is processed, all will have a value of `1`.

Consequent runs will succeed the final `if` test solely because of that.

Change your code to re-initialize *inside* the loop:

```
for i in list1:
    num1 = len(i) 
    num2 = num3 = num4 = 0
    # rest stays the same
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, so foolish of me. newbie to the coding.